# ThinkPad Trackpad multi-finger

Tags: 18.04

I have Ubuntu 18.04 running on my ThinkPad and has been running nearly flawlessly for months.  Very recently two finger right click/scroll and three finger middle click, to put it simply, have stopped working.

I wish I could say specifically what it's doing but it's somewhat arbitrary.  Sometimes two finger scroll works with four fingers, sometimes three finger middle click registers as one finger left click.  Sometimes they all registers as a simple left click.  Sometimes rebooting helps.  I've also looked at xev which seems to agree, if that makes sense.  Any idea what's going on with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running tweaks? It fixed the problem for me on 18.04. Tweaks is a program that allows for customization of various functions like the adjustments you make in your settings. Looks like settings but it has additional options. Available in the Ubuntu store. Tweaks